# Count occurrences of string in lines with boolean AND

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, text

I'm very new to Python but have a need to read the lines of a text file and count the occurrences of multiple strings using boolean AND.  For instance, if a particular line contains 'blue' AND 'green' I need to count the number of lines this is true for.  This is what I have so far.

```
import re
file = open("text.txt")
lines = file.readlines()
print(lines.count('blue')
file.close()
```

Your assistance is appreciated.

Comment: I assume you want to use RegExp because you are importing it?

Comment: Dude welcome to Stackoverflow and welcome to the pythonian world. This is a simple task and it requires looping through your entire file (line by line) and see if each line (str) contains blue and green. [Without regex]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using **Regex**:

```
import re
count = 0
with open(filename, "r") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if re.search(r"\bblue\b", line, flags=re.IGNORECASE) and re.search(r"\bgreen\b", line, flags=re.IGNORECASE):
            count += 1
print(count)
```

- `\b` Regex boundary

Comment: You guys are awesome!  I'm having a great time learning python!

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to match entire words while ignoring case. So, for example, blueberry or greenhouse will not be caught.

The trick we use here is to check the `set` of words in a line is a superset of `{'blue', 'green'}`.

```
import re
from io import StringIO

mystr = StringIO("""animal door read blue
green purple blue yellow
dolphin giraffe turtle blue
life green battle blue""")

counter = 0

# replace mystr with open('file.txt', 'r')
with mystr as fin:
    for line in fin.readlines():
        words = set(line.rstrip('\n').lower().split())
        if words >= {'blue', 'green'}:
            counter += 1

print(counter)  # 2
```